# Trying to track url in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an app where I load an external web page. On that page i have a link that redirects to another url. What i want is to track the url of the external web page from inside my android application so that when that particular link is clicked and the url begins to load, the web view is closed and the user is returned to the home screen of my application

```
String token;
WebView viewer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    viewer = new WebView(this);
    viewer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    viewer.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    setContentView(viewer);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    token = intent.getStringExtra(home.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String home = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/index?token="+token;

    viewer.loadUrl(home);

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && viewer.canGoBack())
    {
        viewer.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


private WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if(url == "http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/api/logout")
        {
            view.clearHistory();
            view.destroy();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: `an app where I load an external web application` ? What i see is that you load an external web page in a WebView. And it is unclear what you want to close exactly.

Comment: okay, yeah i'm basically loading a web page.That web page has a link that redirects to a url. What i want is to track that url from inside my application so that when the link starts to load, the web view should get closed and return to my application.

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @greenapps it doesn't work.

Comment: That is not a very helpfull description. You should exactly tell what you want and what happens or not happens. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this condition is not correct

```
if(url == "http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/api/logout")
```

it should be

```
if(url.equals("http://10.0.2.2:8888/map/api/logout"))
```

because `==` will compare references, not values, while the other one does.

**P.S:** for less changes/bugs in future, use `endsWith()` instead of `equals()`; ex, domain name changed your condition will still valid.

```
if(url.endsWith("map/api/logout"))
```

Comment: That works, but how do i return my user to the home screen of my app if the condition is met? i tried starting an intent to open the page but it didn't work

Comment: @lagfvu if the home screen is the next activity in the stack, just `finish()` the webview activity. if this did not work you have to ask this in a new question and put more code related to the issue, as this question was about detecting/tracking a certain url in webview